# How to make a Web Audio element sound instantly when pressed on mobile?

Tags: javascript, web, audio, mobile, html5-audio

I am finishing up a beat/sample pad project using web audio and JavaScript. When I click on a sample pad, I want it to sound instantly, and this works fine on the desktop version, however, on mobile, the sample will only sound once I have lifted my finger away from the screen. This then creates a lag of sorts, and you definitely wouldn't be able to play along in time with any music for example. Is there a way to get the sample to sound instantly as soon as it's pressed on a mobile device? I've found that the "mousedown" event seems to work best for desktop, but I can't get the same result with anything that I have tried for mobile.

Please feel free to take a look at the Beat pad project here: http://beatpad.dwcreate.co.uk/

I'll post code later if needed.

Many thanks to anyone who can help me with this problem!

Comment: Did the answer below work fo you?

Answer (score 0):

`Audio` element seems to have latency issues on Apple touch devices...not sure about the others. `AudioBuffer` will provide more reliable playback immediacy across browsers.  After some fiddling, it seems the "touchstart" event must be bound on the document and wasn't working when bound on the element.

```js
// samples identified by keyboard key code
const samples = [49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,48,45,61,113,119,101,114,116,121,117,105,111,112,91,93,97,115,100,102,103,104,106,107,108,59,39,122,120,99,118,98,110,109,44,46,47]

// audio contect for decoding and playback
const ctx =  new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)({ latencyHint: 'playback' })

// decoded AudioBuffers we'll create for each sample
audioBuffers = {}

// keyboard keys to render
keys = {}

// track download/decode progress
let totalLoaded = 0

init()

function init() {
  samples.forEach(async keyCode => {
    const url = `https://cøder.com/static/61881209/${keyCode}.mp3`
    const buffer = await (await fetch(url)).arrayBuffer()
    ctx.decodeAudioData(buffer, decoded => {
      audioBuffers[keyCode] = decoded
      fileLoaded() 
    })
  })
}

// keyboard press
document.addEventListener('keypress', playSample)

function fileLoaded() {
  totalLoaded++
  document.querySelector('#progress').innerText = `Samples Loaded: ${totalLoaded} / ${samples.length}`

  if (totalLoaded === samples.length) {
    initKeyboard()
  }
}

function playSample({ keyCode }) {
  // play audio sample from beginning
  const [audioBuffer, key] = [audioBuffers[keyCode], keys[keyCode]]
  if (audioBuffer) {
    const bufferSource = ctx.createBufferSource()
    bufferSource.buffer = audioBuffer;
    bufferSource.connect(ctx.destination);
    bufferSource.start(0);

    requestAnimationFrame(_ => {
      key.classList.remove('pressed')
      requestAnimationFrame(_ => {
        key.classList.add('pressed')
      })
    })
  }
}

// draw keyboard on screen
function initKeyboard() {
  const keyboard = document.createElement('div')
  keyboard.className = 'keyboard'
  
  let row = 0  // keyboard row
  const breakOn = ['q', 'a', 'z'] // start new row
  
  // render each keyboard key
  samples.forEach(keyCode => {
    const char = String.fromCharCode(keyCode)
    const key = document.createElement('div')

    key.className = 'key'
    key.innerText = char
    key.dataset.code = keyCode

    // start new row
    if (breakOn.includes(char)) {
      row++
      key.style.clear = 'both'
      key.style.marginLeft = `${20*row}px`
    }
    
    keys[keyCode] = key
    keyboard.append(key)
  })
  
  // bind click or touch if it's a tablet
  if ('ontouchstart' in window) {
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', handleClick)
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClick)
  }
  
  function handleClick(e) {
    const {dataset: {code}} = e.target
    if (code) {
      playSample({ keyCode: code })
    }
  }

  document.body.innerHTML = ''
  document.body.append(keyboard)
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'open sans light', arial, sans-serif;
  background: #f9f9f9;
}
.keyboard {
  width: 620px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.key {
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 6px;
  user-select: none;
}
.key.pressed {
  animation: keyPress .5s ease-out;
}

@keyframes keyPress {
  0% {
    background: lime;
  }
  100% {
    background: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="progress">Loading...</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events), you might be looking for the `touchstart` event.

```
function onTouchQuick() {
    // ...
}

element.addEventListener("touchstart", onTouchQuick);
```

Comment: Hi! Many thanks for your answer! While touchstart certainly works a lot better, there is still a certain degree of lag. I am looking to have a similar response to what the sample pads on this site( http://sampulator.com/ ) has when on mobile. I have updated my site with the touchstart event for mobile, so you should be able to compare the response times between the two.