# AudioBufferSourceNode.start() doesn't work, or at least activate but doesn t produce any sound, am i doing something wrong?

Tags: javascript, audio, buffer, web-audio-api, audiobuffer

> my goal is to play a sound when a specific key is pressed (me saying the letter on the key pressed), but without html audio tag, with audioBuffers from web-Audio API. 
>   Execpt here, the audioBufferSourceNode created as an item of arraySources, doesn t display any sound when the function .start() is used on it. Dont know whyy
>
> UPDATE : SOLVED arraySources[count].connect(AudCtx.destination) was missing .. !

```js
var myHeader = new Headers({
    'accept':'audio/mpeg',
    'cache-controle':'private',
});

var myInit = {  method: 'GET',
                headers: myHeader,
                mode: 'cors',
                cache:'default' };

var AudCtx = new AudioContext();
arrayRes=[];
arrayBuffers=[];
arraySources=[];

for (var i=0;i<26;i++){
    fetch('./audio/abc'+(i+1)+'.mp3',myInit).then(function(response){
        arrayRes.push(response);
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    })
    .then(function(response){
        return response.arrayBuffer();
    })
    .then(function(buffer){
        console.log(buffer);
        return AudCtx.decodeAudioData(buffer);
    })
    .then(function(decodedData){
        arrayBuffers.push(decodedData);
        console.log(decodedData);
    })
}

var count = 0; 
window.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
    var keycode = e.keyCode;
    var posiArray = e.keyCode-65;
    if (keycode>=65 && keycode<=91){
        console.log("keycode = "+keycode+" & posiArray = "+posiArray);
        console.log("count = "+count);
        arraySources[count] = AudCtx.createBufferSource();
        arraySources[count].buffer = arrayBuffers[posiArray];
        count++;
    }
})

window.addEventListener("click",function(){
    arraySources[count-1].start(0);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>web audio test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give this answer a look, it should do what you're trying to achieve:

[How to make a Web Audio element sound instantly when pressed on mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61881209/how-to-make-a-web-audio-element-sound-instantly-when-pressed-on-mobile/62112502#62112502)

Comment: Thanks, it made me realise i was missing the .connect function, my buffer sources have no destination ...